# Renaming files based on its folder name

Tags: powershell, rename

How do I rename files that is based on its folder name?  In a current folder it has those folder names:

- 2000
- 2001
- ...
- 2014

And in each folder it has:

- 01.xls
- 02.xls
- ...
- 12.xls

How do I rename them in a way, for example, in folder `2000`, `01.xls` becomes `200001.xls`?

Comment: Actually, I was planning to write a VBA code to compare data in small XLS files to the big XLS file that is supposed to contain all data.  I just wanted to make the filenames easier for VBA to read.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below command will get the result you are looking for using `Get-ChildItem` commandlet to get the `.xls` files and then use `Rename-Item` commandlet to perform the renaming accordingly.

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> Get-ChildItem D:\SO_Test -Filter *.xls -Recurse | 
Rename-Item -NewName { $_.Directory.Name+$_.Name}
```